# How to make an image fill a flexbox item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML that uses a `flex container` to house two divs, one containing an image (on the left) and the other one has some text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="wrapper" style="display:flex; background:pink;">

    <div id="image_div">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MvnfA1U.png">
    </div>

    <div id="number_list">
        <h3>One</h3>
        <h3>Two</h3>
        <h3>Three</h3>
        <h3>Four</h3>
        <h3>Five</h3>
        <h3>Six</h3>
        <h3>Seven</h3>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

How do I get the image to increase in size and take the full height of its (pink) container, while:

1. Keeping the image adjacent to the text (only pushing as far right as it needs to go)
2. Maintaining the image's aspect ratio
3. Without cutting off part of the image
4. Without having text overlap the image
5. Keeping it generic (eg no specifying pixel lengths)

Thanks

Comment: Try giving <div id="image_div"  style="flex:1">  and <div id="number_list" style="flex:1">

Comment: @HemaNandagopal, this appears to make the divs of equal width, so now the number list is too far-right. The goal is to have the image div "just big enough" to house the image when it is at full size in its container

Comment: Then specify the img height.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal this causes the text to overlap the image

Comment: @dismantle is it ok to fix a height for the container?

Comment: @dismantle posted an answer,let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still an unsolved issue being asked before in a question of mine. To solve this today, a script is needed.

Answer (score -2):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <div id="wrapper" style="display:flex; background:pink;justify-content:space-between;">
    
        <div id="image_div">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MvnfA1U.png" style="height:100%;">
        </div>
    
        <div id="number_list" style="width:50%">
            <h3>One</h3>
            <h3>Two</h3>
            <h3>Three</h3>
            <h3>Four</h3>
            <h3>Five</h3>
            <h3>Six</h3>
            <h3>Seven</h3>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: add jsfidle and some more info

Comment: no jsfiddle. THere is an SO snippet which is much better

Comment: Nope, won't work. Check dupe link, a question of mine, this is yet to be fixed within the browsers